# Running WPF desktop application from shared network folder

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, runtime-error, desktop-application

I’m facing an issue when running a windows desktop application (WPF .NET 5) from a shared network folder.
The application uses a sql server as a data store.
The application was initially published to a local folder as a self-contained deployment. When transferring the contents of that local folder to a machine in the customer’s network the program runs without any problems – it can connect to the database.
However when I try to run the program from a shared network folder in that same network the app crashes and the windows logs report a series of errors:

> Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: xxxxxxxx Name des fehlerhaften
> Moduls: KERNELBASE.dll, Version: 6.3.9600.20040, Zeitstempel:
> 0x60adc0a6 Ausnahmecode: 0xe0434352 Fehleroffset: 0x0000000000007afc
>
> Application: yyyyyy.exe CoreCLR Version: 5.0.921.35908 .NET Version:
> 5.0.9 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
> Exception Info: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A
> network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
> a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
> accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
> Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11,
> error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>
> Category: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query EventId: 10100 An
> exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for
> context type 'XXXXXXXX'.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related
> or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 26 - Error
> Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>
> Category: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection EventId:
> 20004 An error occurred using the connection to database 'XXXXXXX' on
> server 'XXXXXXXX'.

Since the program produces no connection errors when run directly on the machine in the customer's network it seems it has something to do with running it from a shared network folder. Are there specific options which have to be enabled (I can't see what settings exist for the share in question on the customer's network) for running the application like:

- reading settings from an appsettings.json file
- accessing the sql server

I’ve build a simple test application that doesn’t do much (doesn’t access the database – just displays a hello world window) and I deployed it the same way as mentioned above. Then there is no problem running that test application from the shared network folder.
So any hints on how to approach this problem are appreciated.

Comment: You are probably facing the problem [Windows 10 1803 (and above) running your app from an SMBv1 network share](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-1803-and-applications-on-smb1-shares/ce885799-1e49-4705-a097-835c5a52489f?tab=AllReplies#tabs)

Comment: @TheGeneral can you be more specific: what can be the reason why the server is not accessible from the folder whereas it's accessible from the machine when both are in the same network?